# TSQL SQL 2000 stored proc cursor

Tags: t-sql

I'm new to this board. I have been driving myself crazy trying to find the answer to my problem. 
I created some TSQL code that executes some dynamic SQL in a cursor within a stored proc. The cursor fetches some data from table x, builds a query based data retrieved in table x, runs the query, and returns data. Works like a charm. 
When I add an 'insert into table' to capture the results I get an error: NOTE: only errors with SQL 2000 runs great on SQL 2008.
The operation could not be performed because the OLE DB provider 'MSDAORA' was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'MSDAORA' ITransactionJoin::JoinTransaction returned 0x8004d01b].

Comment: Are you just using SQL Server? MSDAORA is the Oracle provider.
It would help if you show the SQL thats causing the problem.

Comment: I shudder at the thought of a cursor and a distributed transaction and dynamic SQl all in one query. There has to be a better way to do this. Row-by-row processing is bad, you want to work with sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a cursor for this. My guess would be a comflict with the cursor and the insert into table.

Please post code and the problem you are tyring to solve so that we can help you write it correctly.